# How to auto wire spring bean which is configured in Xml file

Tags: spring

How to inject  bean using  auto wire  which is configured in spring configuration xml file

Comment: Autowiring works the same way, regardless if the bean is defined in code or XML.

Answer (score 1):

this is a lazy question, there are tons of books and tutorial for autowiring in the xml.
In the Main class you have to use the BeanFactory/ApplicationContext. The ApplicationContext is better because it implements the BeanFactory and is also suitable for Enterprise environments. The implementation you need of the ApplicationContext is the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext which takes a string parameter that represents the name of the xml with the beans. If you want to use the autowiring in the xml is pretty simple:
autowire="type-of-autowiring-you-want"
I usually prefer autowiring by name, but I prefer to use annotations. A complete example would be:

```
    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
            Person person = context.getBean("person");
            System.out.println("My name is " + person.getName());
            System.out.println("I'm " + person.getAge());
```

so you have to put this in the beans.xml:

```
    <bean id="person" class="com.mypackage.Person" autowire="byName">
    //optional     <property name="name" value="Fausto"/>
    //optional     <property name="age" value="23"/>
    </bean>
```

The result would be:

```
My name is Fausto
I'm 23
```

Simple!
obviously there are different implementations of the autowiring:
byType-byName-construcotr(is the constructor injection)-no(disabled).
if you use the annotations you can reach the same result with the stereotype annotations(Component, Controller, Repository, Service).

Comment: Further information can be found at: https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/autowiring-using-xml-configuration-in-spring.html